# Runtime error : reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error, runtime

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maximumPopulation(vector<vector<int>>& logs) {
        
       
        int g;
        int n=logs.size();
        vector<vector<int>> a(n);
        
        for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++)
        {
        for(int i=j;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            if(logs[n-1-i][0]<logs[0+j][1])
            {
                a[j][1]=logs[0+j][1];
                a[j][0]=logs[0+j][1]-logs[n-1-i][0];
            }
        
                
        }
        } 
      vector<int> p= *std::max_element(a.begin(),a.end());
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(a[i][0]==p[0])
         g=a[i][1];
           
        }
         return g;
    }
};
```

getting so much error after resolving i find got this and this time tym i cant resolve runtime error please help

Comment: `a[j][1]` and `a[j][0]` are not valid indices for `a[j]`, since `a[j]` is an empty vector

Comment: I recommend using `std::vector<std::array<int, 2>>` as the type for `a`.